# Unable to get JSON data in plain text using angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

I am using api to get data into plain text from json data. I am not able to display the data in to the table using angularjs.

here is the sample json

```
{"success":true,"sensorsdata":{"id":1,"devid":"car1","status":"true","CurrentTime":"24-January-2017 03:54:PM"}}
```

here is my code

```
 <body>
        <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">

            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ access.id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ access.devid }}</td>
                    <td>{{ access.status }}</td>
                    <td>{{ access.CurrentTime }}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
       <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
            $http.get("url")
            .then(function (response) { $scope.access = response.data;});
        });
            </script>
            </body>
```

Comment: Are you really trying to call 'url' or did you deliberately take the url out for obfuscation? i.e. $http.get("url") is going to attempt a get of the url 'url'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a key of `sensorsdata` in response and you are accessing `response.data`. Just change that.

Try below code.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("url")
  .then(function (response) { $scope.access = response.sensorsdata;});
});
```

Comment: getting error -  Uncaught ReferenceError: response is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:13

Answer (score 3):

You should change `response.data` to `response.data.sensorsdata`.

```
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("url")
    .then(function (response) { $scope.access = response.data.sensorsdata; });
});
```

Comment: damn you beat me to it, i thought finally i could earn some easy points :D

Comment: @SujalMandal haha :)

Comment: error-  Uncaught ReferenceError: response is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:13

Comment: I could suppose that you change the url, inside `get("url")`. The url is just for prenenting your code? If you already have done this, could you please check the response you get using developer tools, (Chrome->F12->Network find your call and check the response). Does this have the form of the json you have posted?

Comment: sorry i got it ,,actually it was some browser cache problem